# Defining the file Directory; xampp

Tags: php, macos, directory, xampp

I'm running XAMPP for Mac.

When I first started working with PHP, I would define my directory with a variable:

```
 $root = "http://localhost/~aaron/SiteFolder/"; // Dev
 $root = "http://www.sitename.com/";            // Live
```

This will work, but it's a huge annoyance having to comment one out, depending on if I'm editing the dev site or the live site.

I'm slowly transitioning over to OOP habits and want to maximize efficiency if at all possible. So I'm attempting to define ROOT with the current directory as shown here:

```
define("ROOT", dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

This outputs:

```
/Users/aaron/Sites/SiteFolder/
```

This is not entirely useful to me when I'm working on the dev site, because I want to be able to use `ROOT` as a prefix for my images, files, etc.

This obviously won't work:

```
<img src="/Users/aaron/Sites/SiteFolder/images/charizard.png">
```

What do I need to do to fix this problem to properly define my directory?

Comment: Anything preventing you from using relative paths?

Comment: Is there a pre-defined function for getting this information or will I have to manually place it in a variable?

Comment: Relative paths are just that: relative. Imagine you have an HTML file under `/path/to/site/index.html` and an image under `/path/to/site/images/image.png` you can reference the image in the HTML file by simply using `<img src="images/image.png" />`. Or in other words: write the path with the referencing file folder as the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments in my other answer, this is what you could do:

You could create a simple installation page and ask the user for the url where they plan to host your web app.

Then you can set this variable in a database or something.

A lot of web apps do this: Wordpress, Joomla come to mind.

EDIT:

You could also try to build the url using the php $_SERVER variable. You can get the host, port, to build the url.

Unfortunately this could be a problem if someone decides to say host your web app in something other than the root of the domain of subdomain.

Something like 'http://domain/yourwebapphere/'

You wouldn't be able to detect that without the user specifying it. If you used a single endpoint and used an htaccess for redirecting urls, you'd still need to specify a base url in the htacess for it to redirect properly.

EDIT2:

Ok, if you really want to create the url dynamically, here's some psuedo code on how to do it.

```
$protocol = parse_server_protocol($_SERVER['server_protocol']);
$port = $_SERVER['port']
$host = $_SERVER['server_name'];
//For use case where the app is not hosted at root of domain ("http://domain.com/test") for example
$urlroot = parse_root($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

$siteurl = buildRootUrl($protocol, $port, $host, $urlRoot);

//Now save that root url in the database.
```

If you are using htacess to create clean urls, your app would need to know how to write the baseurl in the instance where it is not hosted at the root of the domain.

Comment: I have considered this, but then I've stumbled upon this in Drupal:
`define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());` I guess my ultimate question now is should I use getcwd(); for the live site, and define the http://localhost for the dev site?

Comment: I don't know much about Drupal. But I think the DRUPAL_ROOT is not used for url paths to images. getcwd() gets the filesystem path, which is basically what you've done with  `dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Comment: So what is the usage for `dirname( __FILE__)` ?

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` gets you the filesystem of path of the currently accessed file. In the case you call this on say index.php, it should be the same as getcwd(), but I could be wrong about that though. I made a second edit with some pseudo code on how you could potentially get the url dynamically. You'd still need to do it on installation and save the url to the db with an install script though.

Answer (score 0):

Since that is a url for the image tag, can't you just define your image root directory as `define('ROOT', '/images/')`?

Right now you are getting the directory path.

EDIT:

Sorry I misread the question a bit. Assuming you are talking about public resources like images on your webserver that you want to link to.

Then you can define your root as your base url?

`define('ROOT', 'http://localhost/')` or 
`define('ROOT', 'http://dev.sitename/')` or
`define('ROOT', 'http://localhost/testsite/')`

Comment: I have ROOT defined as above, and the result is `/Users/aaron/Sites/SiteFolder/images/charizard.png` which is not a valid source for the image.

Comment: Right, it is invalid because that is the path. You want the url to the image if you want it displayed. I had misread the question slightly. So you'll want to make your root, the url that you are using. I didn't list it above, but you can do define('ROOT', '/') to do a relative url.

Comment: Hmm, I realized that you mentioned that you used to do what I just mentioned. I'm not sure I understand why you doing it that way. Is the folder you are referencing in the public accessible directory of your webserver?

Comment: Yes, this works, but I would much rather not have to use URLs. Any ideas how I can utilize dir( __file__ ) or getcwd(); to manage this?

Comment: To answer your question, when I direct myself to `/Users/aaron/Sites/SiteFolder/` in my browser it will take me to `file:///Users/aaron/Sites/SiteFolder`. what can I do to manage this public accessible directory?

Comment: I think the `file://` is only accessible for the files on your computer. So an outside user would not be able to access it. I don't think it's a bad thing to define development and production urls for for your resources in a configuration file. You could use some of the information from `$_SERVER` to dynamically build the root url. But no matter what you need to a url and not a path that is local to your file system. But maybe I misunderstand the question, which I'm apt to do.

Comment: I guess why I'm asking this is because if say I develop a web-app (forum system for example), I won't know the end user's URL, so I would ideally like to define the path to the directory so it doesn't matter, be it hosted on a web server or localhost. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

as CodeIgniter uses, there's a config variable in config.php file:

```
$config["base_path"] = "/projects/mysite/"; //relative to http://localhost
```

and there's a helper function :

```
function base_url(){
     return $config["base_path"];
}
```

and in your urls you use it like

if you use smarty:

```
<img src="{base_url()}assets/images/1.jpg">
```

or direct php:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/1.jpg">
```

and when you upload your site to the web, just change your base url to:

```
$config["base_path"] = "/";
```

and all working again.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so I never have to edit base_path by using `getcwd();` or `dirname( __file__ )` ?

Comment: Well, checking the $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] and comparing with localhost or 127.0.0.1 and then using $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] might help, but manual definition is better I think. Because you won't change it many times.